# How to convert text file from BASH to HTML?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, html

I already extract some text from bash using command "systemctl status ddos.service" bellow :

[image]

But, when I generate report in html for text that I extract above, it show all text in one line, like capture bellow :

[image]

My question is : How we can put result in html report same with result in bash ?? (I mean that result in html report not in one line like my capture above for html report, but I want capture in HTML report like result in bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it inside `<pre></pre>`?

> The [`<Pre>` Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) defines preformatted text.
>
> Text in a `<pre>` element is displayed in a fixed-width font, and the
> text preserves both spaces and line breaks. The text will be displayed
> exactly as written in the HTML source code.